# Can I wrap the Content/text value of a RadioButton in WPF?

Tags: xaml, radio-button, textblock, word-wrap

I have some XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock x:Name="KeyLWP" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="120">A Letter or Word or Phrase
    </TextBlock>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtnCandidateVal1" Content="Two wrongs don't make a Wright Brothers Grimm was the Thingamabob Dylan Thomas Jefferson Airplane">
        </RadioButton>
```

...where, with a long string assigned to a RadioButton's Content, it simply falls off the edge of the earth. How can I get it to wrap, if necessary, as I can with the TextWrapping and MaxWidth properties of TextBlock? Or must I pair a TextBlock with each RadioButton, eschewing the RadioButton's Content/Text property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have some options, you could go make it do so in the Radio Button Style Template so it applies to all of them, or at the instance level just a quick;

```
<RadioButton>
   <RadioButton.Content>
      <TextBlock Text="Wrap My Content Pretty Pretty Please" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Or there's other options also, let me know if there's a specific scenario and we'll get ya sorted.

Comment: Thanks, Chris; I had to add a MaxWidth val, too, but that was easy enough.